# error : mi_cmd_stack_list_frames: Not enough frames in stack

Tags: iphone, xcode, stack, device

Ho everyone, my problem is that when I build and run for my device (ipod) I've got an error:
here is what is in my console :

```
dyld: could not load inserted library: /usr/lib/libignitor.dylib

Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen at this time.)
mi_cmd_stack_list_frames: Not enough frames in stack.
mi_cmd_stack_list_frames: Not enough frames in stack.
```

I can't solve this problem and I have this problem with all my projects !! I can run only on the simulator. sorry for my english I'm french :)